# Why does Firefox ignores bottom margin of flex-item?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

It respects `margin-bottom` only when there is enough room for it. Otherwise Firefox behaves as if there is no `margin-bottom` at all.

Chrome Full:

[image: Chrome Full]

Chrome Shrinked:

[image: Chrome Shrinked]

Firefox Shrinked:

[image: Firefox Shrinked]

Is it correct behaviour of flexbox? How to fix it?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/vbarbarosh/pen/NgqPVr?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #8f8;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  background: #f88;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grow"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, facilis omnis inventore, illum eos quis fuga quos id, labore consectetur quas. Unde sed nemo nobis recusandae saepe ex nulla accusantium?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias asperiores a enim magnam voluptatem. Ab sint possimus quis odit vero explicabo unde quod rem, quasi voluptatibus cupiditate voluptatem veritatis repudiandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grow"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Consider adding a `flex-basis` to `.grow`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLVpZN?editors=1100

Comment: @Michael_B Using `flex-basis` you will force to have `.grow` elements with at least 1px height. When screen is too small I don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what's happening: When the window is too small, the `<div class="grow"></div>` elements shrink all the way down to a height of 0 pixels. Now Firefox doesn't even bother rendering them. So you don't have any element underneath the `<div class="content"></div>` element, and therefore the bottom margin of that element doesn't get applied. A page with just one element with bottom margin has the same effect.

I would set up your html/css differently so you don't run into this problem. You can use a container around the `content` div and apply padding on that for example.

Comment: Is it correct behavior (Chrome and IE does not have this issue)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stick to `flex-direction: row` with just one flex item having `margin: auto`. Inside of it I put my container. That way it works in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari without issues:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/vbarbarosh/pen/eRNxwQ?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  /* when using *column* Safari 9.0 and below will ignore bottom margins */
  flex-direction: row; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #f88;
}
.content-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  background: #8f8;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, facilis omnis inventore, illum eos quis fuga quos id, labore consectetur quas. Unde sed nemo nobis recusandae saepe ex nulla accusantium?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias asperiores a enim magnam voluptatem. Ab sint possimus quis odit vero explicabo unde quod rem, quasi voluptatibus cupiditate voluptatem veritatis repudiandae.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```