# Flexbox last child margin collapsing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with a fixed height and overflow-y set to scroll. Inside the container I have children with a value of margin-bottom: 2rem.

In Firefox the margin-bottom of the last child is ignored and I can't figure out why? It appears to have something to do with overflow. Chrome & Safari work as expected.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/y7sn0rgb/1/

CSS

```
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        background: grey;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .comment {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe overflow is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389126/why-does-firefox-ignores-bottom-margin-of-flex-item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout

Comment: @kukkuz "The overflow property applies only to content. It doesn't apply to padding or margins." ... but it works properly when I use padding instead of margin?

Comment: see as I said, it is the implementation difference between browsers and we may have to live with it... I linked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout) because it shows a similar behavior in the *row* direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin-bottom` to `padding-bottom`

Comment: Yes, I know but I'm trying to understand what's happening.

Comment: The margin gets outside of the box that's why

Comment: Right, but why is it going outside of the parent? Without overflow the margin is there. With overflow the margin is outside of the parent container.

Comment: You can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element

And some doc here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: @AlexLacayo implementation difference between both the browsers I guess - *padding* can be used...